# how to get a portion of a number in haskell

Tags: haskell, numbers

I have this number:

```
1.89
```

but I want this part of the number

```
0.89
```

is there a way to do that? (Haskell)

Comment: So you want the non-integral part? Depending on *what* you want, several solutions can exists. For example taking of the most significant digit will also return `0.89`.

Comment: Yes, is there any function that can do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the type of the number is an instance of `RealFrac`, you can make use of [**`properFraction :: (Integral a, RealFrac b) => b -> (a, b)`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:properFraction) to obtain a 2-tuple with the first item the integral part, and the second the floating part. For example:

```
Prelude> properFraction 1.89
(1,0.8899999999999999)
```

You thus can use [**`snd :: (a, b) -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:snd) to obtain the fractional part:

```
Prelude> snd (properFraction 1.89)
0.8899999999999999
```

If the number is negative, both the integral part and the fractional part will be negative:

```
Prelude> properFraction (-1.89)
(-1,-0.8899999999999999)
```